# Regex search and replace files in project

Tags: regex, sed, atom-editor

I'm trying to change `'class'=>'smart-form'` to `'class'=>'smart-form','target'=>'_blank'`

I have the following regex to search lines in all my project files matching this criteria (I used *regex101* tool to generate the following regex ):

```
\<\?php \$form = ActiveForm::begin\(\['id' => 'my-form', 'action'=>\['(\w*)\/(\w*)'\], 'options'=>\[('class'=>'smart-form')]]\); \?>
```

It matches very well when I search lines in my project files with *Atom editor*

However, I can't use the replace field to replace those lines using this substitution:

```
$3,'target'=>'_blank'
```

Is there a package for *Atom editor* to optimize this task ?

As altenative I could use sed (or perhaps a combination of bash tools provided by MINGW32) But what command I should use?, I'm not experienced using this tool.

Snippet:
https://regex101.com/r/nC4hI0/1

Comment: I love using regex to change code :) What are you trying to end up with? When I checked it I get 'class'=>'smart-form','target'=>'_blank'

Comment: I'm trying to change `'class'=>'smart-form'` to `'class'=>'smart-form','target'=>'_blank'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the entire string, can you just match on the part that you're trying to replace?

```
('class'=>'smart-form')
```

Then your replace, `$1,'target'=>'_blank'`, would work without removing the rest of the match.

If that's not specific enough, the first solution off the top of my head would be to add captures to the before & after parts, and make your replace like `$1$4,'target'=>'_blank'$5` (numbers may need adjustment to be correct).

Comment: I have to search the entire string because it can match very similar ones that I don't want to do that replace. So that's why i just replace a small portion of the entire string search

Comment: probably the best answer then. Unless you can give some examples of what must, may, must not, match to better refine your regex, then I would do the before and after capture as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '\#\<?php \$form = ActiveForm::begin(\['id' => 'my-form', 'action'=>\['([[:alnum:]_]*)\/([[:alnum:]_]*)'\], 'options'=>\[('class'=>'smart-form')\]\]); ?># {
   s/'class'=>'smart-form'/&,'target'=>'_blank'/
   }' YourFile
```

- posix sed version
- take your all fingerprint as regex but certainly too big for your real need
- Assuming the regex matching is a full line (should change if parsed on several line or other info could appear on the same line)